# RuntimeError: qgis._gui cannot import type '\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd' from PyQt5.QtCore

Tags: python, pyqt5, qgis, pyqgis

i am trying to set a venv to use qgis processing algorithms in a standalone python script. since i am using sublime text, i created a build system and provided the path to python.exe file that gets downloaded with qgis. after creating venv i ran this

```
from qgis.core import *
```

but it throwed an error saying that **PyQt5.QtCore** module is not there. So i activated the venv and installed PyQt5 with the command

> pip install PyQt5==5.15.3

. then the above line worked but when i ran the following code

```
from qgis.core import *
import qgis.utils
```

it is throwing this error: **RuntimeError: qgis._gui cannot import type '\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd' from PyQt5.QtCore**

perhaps installing PyQt5 separately was a bad idea but because of the first error i had to.

i am on windows and i need to run it on sublime text or jupyter notebook. please provide any sources or solutions that you are aware of. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it's not advised to install PyQt5 from pip, because apparently QGIS comes already with a specific PyQt version and this can be the conflict. I think this could be the problem that you have.

I recommend you to look at [this other question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/415424/runtimeerror-qgis-gui-cannot-import-type-from-pyqt5-qtcore) where your problem is solved.

Basically you have to go to QGIS `bin`, in Program Files (default), find `qgis-bin.env`, open it and copy all the underlined enviroment variables into your enviroment variables as system variables.

I hope this helps you, tell if you still have errors and checkout the other question for further information as it is explained step by step with images.

Comment: i already tried doing that. as mentioned in that [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/415424/runtimeerror-qgis-gui-cannot-import-type-from-pyqt5-qtcore) question i uninstalled PyQt5 and added all the paths manually to my system variables. but unfortunately it is not working. since i uninstalled PyQt5...this time i am getting this error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtCore

Comment: Could you be using a different Python from the installed one by QGIS installation? To be sure, Try [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/394459/error-no-module-named-pyqt5-qtcore-in-qgis-standalone-application)

Comment: i think i identified the issue. initially i followed these [reference](https://guides.lib.utexas.edu/gis/python-qgis-scripting#:~:text=To%20verify%20your%20QGIS%20Python,Now%20type%20from%20qgis.) steps and created a duplicate of **python.exe** and renamed it to **python3qgis.exe**. in the cmd (after activating venv) if i run the **python3qgis** then both the import statements are working but if i run just **python** then i am getting the above mentioned error. how can i resolve this?

Comment: If you review the point two of the reference you will see that you had renamed the duplicated of python.exe to python3qgis, try to revert this change (maybe renaming this file back to python.exe, tho I'm not sure at all if it will work)

Comment: in the folder QGIS/apps/python39 there are already two (**python.exe**, **python3.exe**) python exe files that came with installation. i created a duplicate of python3 and renamed it to **python3qgis.exe**. finally that folder has three python exe files. i have provided that same path in system variables and created 
 a venv. since that's the first path i think venv can execute any one of those three and that's why it is working in cmd. but if go to **Scripts** folder in **venv**...there is only one exe (**python.exe**). is there a way to work around this or can i delete those extra two?

Comment: I would leave the two python exe that came with the installation

Comment: i deleted the duplicate exe i created and tried to run those import statements in cmd and its working. but when i create a new venv and try to run the same lines in cmd of venv..it is throwing a no module error

Comment: And have you all the underlined environment variables in `qgis-bin.env` into your environment variables as system variables?

Comment: yes, but unfortunately it is not working

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution finally. instead of manually adjusting paths, i opened python console in qgis and ran the follwing lines

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

I appended the list i got from above lines to system paths at the beginning of my script. here is the code

```
import sys
paths = sys.path
qgispaths = ['C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.0/apps/qgis/./python', 'C:/Users/pamidiashoka/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\\profiles\\default/python', 'C:/Users/pamidiashoka/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\\profiles\\default/python/plugins', 'C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.0/apps/qgis/./python/plugins', 'C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 3.26.0\\apps\\qgis\\python', 'C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 3.26.0\\apps\\qgis\\python\\plugins', 'C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 3.26.0\\apps\\qt5\\plugins', 'C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 3.26.0\\apps\\gdal', 'C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 3.26.0\\apps\\qt5\\bin', 'C:\\Users\\pamidiashoka\\Documents', 'C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 3.26.0\\bin\\python39.zip', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS32~1.0\\apps\\Python39\\DLLs', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS32~1.0\\apps\\Python39\\lib', 'C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 3.26.0\\bin', 'C:\\Users\\pamidiashoka\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS32~1.0\\apps\\Python39', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS32~1.0\\apps\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS32~1.0\\apps\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS32~1.0\\apps\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS32~1.0\\apps\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:/Users/pamidiashoka/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\\profiles\\default/python', 'C:\\Users/pamidiashoka/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\\profiles\\default/python/plugins\\qgis2web', 'C:\\Users\\pamidiashoka\\AppData\\Roaming\\QGIS\\QGIS3\\profiles\\default\\python\\plugins']

for i in range(len(qgispaths)):
    if qgispaths[i] not in paths:
        sys.path.append(qgispaths[i])
```

Now i am able to import all the qgis modules and processing algorithms.

But whenever i run a script that has at least one processing algorithm, it is throwing the following warning/message

> QTemporaryDir: Unable to remove
> "C:\Users\pamidiashoka\AppData\Local\Temp\python-XwLsCo" most
> likely due to the presence of read-only files.

I am not sure whether i should be concerned about it or not...but i am able to do what i want to.